# find file physical directories location in drupal 7

Tags: nodes

I have news feed in drupal website. The news feed is XML format and can be read as https://www.mysite.ac.uk/news.xml. I can see via admin news content type. Now what I want to access or in other word how I can find physical location of this xml file in drupal directories. I have check root level and I cannot see any XML (news.xml) file there.

Many Thanks in advanced

Comment: It's dynamically generated, no physical xml file actually exists

Comment: I have issue with this XML file basically, I got few lines at top empty which is causing issue with other integration, how I can I solve this???

Comment: Most probably the feed is generated by a view so you could check the views settings and especially the "HEADERS" section and see what is causing the empty lines.

Comment: @user47027, Your 2nd question is different from the first, you should rewrite the question and add an example of the XML being output from news.xml so the problem can be assessed.